# Delete record from todo list in ReactJS giving error

Tags: reactjs

Am learning ReactJS and building my todo application.
However am facing an issue when I try to delete a task.

I have two files TodoList.js and TodoItems.js

TodoList.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TodoItems from './TodoItems';

class TodoList extends Component {

    //Function to handle adding tasks    
    addTask(event) {
        //Get task Value
        let task = this.refs.name.value;

        //Newitem Object
        if (task !== "") {
            let newItem = {
                text: task,
                key: Date.now()
            }
            this.setState({
                items: this.state.items.concat(newItem)
            });

            this.refs.name.value = ""; //Blank out the task input box
        }
    }

    deleteItem(key) {
        var filteredItems = this.state.items.filter(function (item) {
            return (item.key !== key);
        });

        this.setState({
            items: filteredItems
        });
    }


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
        this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
        this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="todoListMain">
                <div className="header">
                    <form>
                        <input placeholder="Enter Task" id="name" ref="name"></input>
                        <button type="button" onClick={this.addTask}>Add Task</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div className="list">
                    <TodoItems entries={this.state.items} delete={this.deleteItem} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

TodoItems.js has following code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class TodoItems extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }


    delete(key) {
        this.props.delete(key);
    }

    listTasks(item) {
        return <li key={item.key} onClick={() => this.delete(item.key)}>{item.text}</li>
    }


    render() {
        let entries = this.props.entries;
        let listItems = entries.map(this.listTasks);

        return (
            <ul className="theList">
                {listItems}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default TodoItems;
```

I am getting an error on deleting task when clicked on it.

and I am getting error as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXTAQ.png)

I guess it means function delete is not defined but it has been defined still am getting an error.
Can anyone explain how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never attempt to modify your props directly, if something in your components affects how it is rendered, put it in your state :

```
this.state = {
    entries: props.entries
};
```

To delete your element, just filter it out of your `entries` array :

```
    delete(key) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            entries: prevState.entries.filter(item => item.key !== key)
        }))
    }
```

And now the render function :

```
    render() {
        const { entries } = this.state //Takes the entries out of your state

        return (
            <ul className="theList">
                {entries.map(item => <li key={item.key} onClick={this.delete(item.key)}>{item.text}</li>)}
            </ul>
        );
    }
```

Full code :

```
class TodoItems extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            entries: props.entries
        };
    }

    delete = key => ev => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            entries: prevState.entries.filter(item => item.key !== key)
        }))
    }

    render() {
        const { entries } = this.state

        return (
            <ul className="theList">
                {entries.map(item => <li key={item.key} onClick={this.delete(item.key)}>{item.text}</li>)}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

You should also try to never use `var`. If you do not plan to modify a variable, use `const`, otherwise, use `let`.

---

EDIT : The error shown in your edit come from `listTasks` not being bound to your class. To solve it you can either bind it (as shown in an other answer below) or convert it in another function :

```
listTasks = item => {
    return <li key={item.key} onClick={() => this.delete(item.key)}>{item.text}</li>
}
```

Short syntax :

```
listTasks = ({ key, text }) => <li key={key} onClick={() => this.delete(key)}>{text}</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, much appreciated. I am still getting error I have modified my question to include complete code. Great if you can suggest me whats the issue.

Comment: You're welcome. Just noticed my code had a typo, I changed the `delete` function to an arrow function that can also accept the click event, otherwise it would be called every time your component renders and `this` would be undefined.

Comment: I also added a solution to the problem you gave in your edit

Comment: Thanks Treycos, it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Check [this section](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance) of the React Docs. You either have to bind your class functions in the constructor or use arrow functions.

```
class TodoItems extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        // ...
        this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
    }

    delete(key) {
        this.props.delete(key);
    }

    // Or without binding explicitly:
    delete2 = (key) => {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried the solutions but doesnt seem  to work for me.I have modified my question to have complete code, I am still getting error on deleting, can you please help.

Comment: Use the techniques in the answer for the list Tasks method, too. Problem with your solution is that 'this' is not bound in the list Tasks function.

Comment: Thankyou, your suggestion really helped

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
onClick={this.delete(item.key)}
// passes the result of `this.delete(item.key)` as the callback
```

By this:

```
onClick={() => this.delete(item.key)}
// triggers `this.delete(item.key)` upon click
```